# Automatically insert parenthesis around region without keybinding

Tags: electric-pair-mode, parentheses

Is there a way to automatically insert parenthesis (or other s-expressions) around a *highlighted region* by only typing `(, {, ",` etc.? I don't want to have to use a key bind (`M-(`) for that. It's a common feature in modern text editors like VSCode, so I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in emacs.

Edit: I have `delete-selection-mode` on, but in general I want this behavior to trump all others. So if a region is selected, no matter if `delete-selection-mode` is on or off, typing the start symbol of an s-expression would wrap the region in the s-expression. I also just realized that `electric-pair-mode` includes this feature. But I don't want the other features of `electric-pair-mode`, namely that it inserts a pair whenever you type the starting pair, no matter if a region is selected.

Comment: Please *specify* the behavior you're looking for - it's not clear. If you just mean typing a `(` etc. whenever the region is selected, that seems very limiting. With `delete-selection-mode` ON it prevents replacing the selected text with that char. With it off, it prevents inserting the char at point. Please give a recipe, saying what you do at each step, what you see now when doing that, and what you want to see instead.

Comment: @Drew sorry I wasn't clear. I've updated the question, hopefully that's clear enough

Comment: Thx............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Electric pair mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html#index-Electric-Pair-mode) is the closest built-in feature to what you're looking for. It inserts both an opening and a closing parentheses when you type one, with customizations to sometimes only insert what you type if there is already a matching unbalanced parenthesis. If the region is active, the parentheses are inserted around the region, even if Delete selection mode is active.

It doesn't appear to have an option to only trigger when the region is active. You can disable the insertion of the matching parenthesis when the region is inactive with a few lines of code, [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) the function that is called (via [`post-self-insert-hook`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps-and-Minor-Modes.html)) after typing a character when Electric pair mode is active.

```
(electric-pair-mode)
(defun only-if-use-region (func &rest args)
  (if (use-region-p)
      (apply func args)))
(advice-add 'electric-pair-post-self-insert-function :around 'only-if-use-region)
```

Comment: thank you! that worked!